# Special symbols used with START in neo4j with Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
START node=node:TEST_INDEX('*:*') 
WHERE node.nodeName =~ '" + nodeName + "' 
RETURN node.nodeName as nodeName
```

**In this particular query what does *:* means?**

I have replaced this query with

```
MATCH(node:TESTDATA) 
WHERE node.nodeName =~  '(?i)CXH.*'
RETURN node.nodeName as nodeName
```

But the result returned is totally different it should return the same result as expected.

Comment: Just to note the START clause has been deprecated for some time now (since 3.0 I think), and if you're using any recent version of Neo4j you shouldn't be using it. Just use a MATCH instead.

Comment: I know about it thats why i am trying to migrate the code but the issue is to understand the symbol not the change of query

Comment: your first query doesn't execute. as nodeName has to come from somewhere. You can use a parameter for it. I guess TEST_INDEX represents TEST_DATA label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query ('*:*') means give me all index columns and all index values.

Below is taken from neo4j ver 3.1 documentation, http://we-yun.com/doc/3.1/neo4j-developer-manual-3.1-dotnet.pdf

When finding starting points through legacy indexes (Node by index query)

> When the starting point can be found by more complex Lucene queries,
>   this is the syntax to use: node:index-name("query").This allows you to
>   write more advanced index queries.

Query

```
START n = node:nodes("name:A")
RETURN n
```

The node indexed with name "A" is returned by the query.

```
Result
+-------------------+
| n                 |
+-------------------+
| Node[0]{name:"A"} |
+-------------------+
1 row
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same.

```
MATCH(node:TESTDATA) 
WHERE node.nodeName = $nodeName
RETURN node.nodeName as nodeName
```

The START index lookup in your first query just says: Give me everything from that index, which you have with the TESTDATA label.

It was actually not using the index for lookup which is not smart.

If you now create an index on :TESTDATA(nodeName) it will use it in the query and so your query will be much faster.

Comment: Michael The main question is still unaswered 

START node=node:TEST_INDEX('*:*') 
WHERE node.nodeName =~ '" + nodeName + "' 
RETURN node.nodeName as nodeName

In this particular query what does : means?